# Datetime is not shown in Firefox browser for AngularJs project

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-bootstrap

I have been working in an ASP.NET Webform project where AngularJs is used. In a form angularJs datetime picker is used to show date and time. Whenever the form is open datetime should show in the fields. The problem is it’s **working in Chrome browser** but **in Firefox datetime is not showing while the page is load** whenever the form is load in the first time. The field shows blank. The code for the datetime control is given bellow.

```
<div class="angular-date-picker">
    <angular-date-picker ng-model="UserDateTimeSettings.SelectedDate"
                         format="UserDateTimeSettings.DateFormat"
                         selected-date="UserDateTimeSettings.SetDatePickerDate"
                         date-changed="dateChanged(value)">
    </angular-date-picker>
</div>
<div ng-class="datePickerClass">
    <div class="angular-time-picker">
        <uib-timepicker ng-model="UserDateTimeSettings.TimePickerDate" 
                        ng-change="TimePickerChanged()" 
                        class="custombtn bs-theme-color" 
                        hour-step="hstep" 
                        minute-step="mstep" 
                        show-meridian="UserDateTimeSettings.IsAmPmVisible">
        </uib-timepicker>
    </div>
    <div class="due-date-zone">{{UserDateTimeSettings.AbbreviatedName}}</div>
</div>
```

In Firefox no error message is given in console either. Can anyone help me how to solve the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem is the date format. The date which I am receiving from API is in incorrect format and Firefox does not parse it. This is why datepicker control can not show the date.